# Un-flatten rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

With a dataframe like this:

```
date           user    sales_blue     sales_red
2019/06/01        A            30            50
2019/06/01        B            60            70
2019/06/02        A            25            35
2019/06/02        B            42            52
```

I'm trying to get to the following:

```
date           user    color    sales
2019/06/01        A     blue       30
2019/06/01        A      red       50
2019/06/01        B     blue       60
2019/06/01        B      red       70
2019/06/02        A     blue       25
2019/06/02        A      red       35
2019/06/02        B     blue       42
2019/06/02        B      red       52
```

This is fairly doable in a kind of "manual" way by using loops, but for performance reasons I'd be looking for a more efficient solution which doesn't involve looping in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use *all* of a column's name to identify a row, `melt` is usually the go-to.  However, when you want to use a smaller part of a column's name, where the prefix is a constant, the generic, more user-friendly version of `melt` is called `wide_to_long`.

Not only will this cleanly handle prefixes, it can be scaled to handle multiple different prefixes.

```
pd.wide_to_long(
    df, stubnames='sales', i=['date', 'user'], j='color', suffix='\w+', sep='_'
).reset_index(-1)
```

```
                color  sales
user date
A    2019/06/01  blue     30
     2019/06/01   red     50
B    2019/06/01  blue     60
     2019/06/01   red     70
A    2019/06/02  blue     25
     2019/06/02   red     35
B    2019/06/02  blue     42
     2019/06/02   red     52
```

---

To generalize this behavior to melt more than a single column:

```
print(df)

         date user  sales_blue  sales_red  calls_blue  calls_red
0  2019/06/01    A          30         50           3          4
1  2019/06/01    B          60         70           1          2
2  2019/06/02    A          25         35           4          6
3  2019/06/02    B          42         52           5          7
```

---

```
pd.wide_to_long(
  df, stubnames=['sales', 'calls'], i=['date', 'user'], j='color', suffix='\w+', sep='_'
).reset_index(-1)
```

```
                color  sales  calls
date       user
2019/06/01 A     blue     30      3
           A      red     50      4
           B     blue     60      1
           B      red     70      2
2019/06/02 A     blue     25      4
           A      red     35      6
           B     blue     42      5
           B      red     52      7
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). And in order to remove the prefixes from the colors you can slice the strings with the `str` accessor. If you need the specified order just add `.sort_values('date')` as @anky suggests.

```
out = df.melt(id_vars=['date', 'user'], var_name='color', value_name='sales')
out['color'] = out.color.str[6:]
```

---

```
print(out)

       date    user color  sales
0  2019/06/01    A  blue     30
1  2019/06/01    B  blue     60
2  2019/06/02    A  blue     25
3  2019/06/02    B  blue     42
4  2019/06/01    A   red     50
5  2019/06/01    B   red     70
6  2019/06/02    A   red     35
7  2019/06/02    B   red     52
```

Comment: This is amazing, didn't know about this method. For the sake of completeness, what to do if there are multiple vars to pivot? For instance, `['sales_blue', 'sales_red', 'calls_blue', 'calls_red']` should become `['sales', 'calls']` with a blue/red index

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but seems like the problem altogehter would be quite different. Why don't you ask a new question? Do ping me here if you do :) @jivan

Comment: sure :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959241/using-df-melt-with-multiple-variables-to-unpivot-in-pandas

Comment: Oh those are columns @jivan I see what you mean. Well you could still go with `melt`, what would need some extra work there is the slicing of the color column to get the colors